# Is it safe to bind Application context in its onCreate?

Tags: android, android-context

Let's assume we have a custom `App extends Application`.

I understand that wherever possible `getApplicationContext()` method should be used, but it's only applicable if you're within a scope that provides this method. Sometimes you need to access it outside of it and that's why I started wondering.

Here's the sample code

```
public class App extends Application
{
    private static App instance = null;

    public static App getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Does `App.getContext()` return the same context `getApplicationContext()` would return in an appropriate scope? Is it safe to bind the App context like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifetime of `static`s is practically the same as your `Application`. It's safe in the sense that there won't be a memory leak and it will always refer to the correct `Application`.

`getApplicationContext()` returns the `Application` object which also is-a `Context`.

However, `static` data like this is a design smell you should try to avoid. It adds unnecessary coupling to your code, making components harder to test in isolation. Instead, consider passing a `Context` as a parameter where one is needed.

For a good article about what a particular kind of `Context` such as `Application` is good for, read http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: +that's a nice and comprehensive article you linked.